# Convert an array of objects into a nested array of objects based on string property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree, javascript-objects, lodash

I am stuck on a problem trying to convert a flat array of objects into a nested array of objects based the name property.

What is the best way to convert the `input` array to resemble the structure of the `desiredOutput` array?

```
var input = [
    { 
        name: 'foo', 
        url: '/somewhere1',
        templateUrl: 'foo.tpl.html',
        title: 'title A', 
        subtitle: 'description A' 
    },
    { 
        name: 'foo.bar', 
        url: '/somewhere2', 
        templateUrl: 'anotherpage.tpl.html', 
        title: 'title B', 
        subtitle: 'description B' 
    },
    { 
        name: 'buzz.fizz',
        url: '/another/place',
        templateUrl: 'hello.tpl.html',  
        title: 'title C',  
        subtitle: 'description C' 
    },
    { 
        name: 'foo.hello.world', 
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'world.tpl.html',
        title: 'title D',   
        subtitle: 'description D' 
    }
]

var desiredOutput = [
    {
        name: 'foo',
        url: '/somewhere1',
        templateUrl: 'foo.tpl.html',
        data: {
            title: 'title A',
            subtitle: 'description A'
        },
        children: [
            {
                name: 'bar',
                url: '/somewhere2', 
                templateUrl: 'anotherpage.tpl.html',
                data: {
                    title: 'title B', 
                    subtitle: 'description B'
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'hello',
                data: {},
                children: [
                    {
                        name: 'world',
                        url: '/',
                        templateUrl: 'world.tpl.html',
                        data: {
                            title: 'title D',   
                            subtitle: 'description D'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'buzz',
        data: {},
        children: [
            {
                name: 'fizz',
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'world.tpl.html',
                data: {
                    title: 'title C',   
                    subtitle: 'description C'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Note the order of the objects in the input array is not guaranteed.
This code will be running in a Node.js environment and I am open to using libraries such as lodash to achieve the desired output.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add your code in your question

Comment: I can't the code is longer than the question so Stackoverflow won't allow me to. Hence the paste bin link. I wanted the data set to be detailed enough to fully express the problem.

Comment: So the parent-child relationship is based on `input[].name` split by `.`? Or can you formalize that relationship further?

Comment: @matt_d_rat for sure you can, and you need to ! Include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.

Comment: @AhmedFasih Yes exactly, like a string representation of the object notation.

Comment: @Magicprog.fr The form would not submit, stackoverflow error validation stated my code was longer than my question. So I physically couldn't submit the form. Hence the paste bin.

Comment: @Magicprog.fr Ok that was weird, it let me do it when I edited it. It didn't when I originally first posted. Weird.

Comment: @matt_d_rat So just paste a part of your code, for example, you don't need to paste the entire `input` array but just a part of it to make it understandable, or extend your question, as you want.

Comment: Your desired output has `foo.hello.hello` instead of `foo.hello.world`, FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Lodash (because why on earth would you want to manipulate complex data without a utility library). Here's [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Wolfy87/f5dfrkcr/).

```
function formatRoute(route) {
    return _.merge(_.pick(route, ['url', 'templateUrl']), {
        name: route.name.split('.'),
        data: _.pick(route, ['title', 'subtitle']),
        children: []
    });
}

function getNameLength(route) {
    return route.name.length;
}

function buildTree(tree, route) {
    var path = _.slice(route.name, 0, -1);

    insertAtPath(tree, path, _.merge({}, route, {
        name: _.last(route.name)
    }));

    return tree;
}

function insertAtPath(children, path, route) {
    var head = _.first(path);

    var match = _.find(children, function (child) {
        return child.name === head;
    });

    if (path.length === 0) {
        children.push(route);
    }
    else {
        if (!match) {
            match = {
                name: head,
                data: {},
                children: []
            };
            children.push(match);
        }

        insertAtPath(match.children, _.rest(path), route);
    }
}


// Map the routes into their correct formats.
var routes = _.sortBy(_.map(input, formatRoute), getNameLength);

// Now we can reduce this well formatted array into the desired format.
var out = _.reduce(routes, buildTree, []);
```

It works by reshaping the initial input so as to split the names into arrays and add the data / children properties. Then it reduces the data over `buildTree` which uses a mutating function ( :( ) to insert the current item in the reduce at the given path.

The strange `if (!match)` part makes sure that missing segments are added in if they're not explicitly specified in the initial data set with a URL etc.

The last two lines that actually do the work should probably be in a little function, and it could do with some JSDoc. It's just a shame I didn't get it completely recursive, I'm relying on array mutation to insert the route object deep within the tree.

Should be simple enough to follow though.

Comment: I like that you've split the efforts out into separate functions, makes the code easy to follow. I will try out your solution along with the others posted and vote on which one best suits my needs. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: I have accepted your answer @Olical because for me it was the easiest to understand and it solved the problem. All of the other submissions also worked and were equally as good though.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses only native JS methods. It can be optimized for sure, but I left it as is to make it easier to follow along (or so I hope it is). I also took care to not modify the original input as JS passes objects by reference.

```js
var input = [{
  name: 'foo',
  url: '/somewhere1',
  templateUrl: 'foo.tpl.html',
  title: 'title A',
  subtitle: 'description A'
}, {
  name: 'foo.bar',
  url: '/somewhere2',
  templateUrl: 'anotherpage.tpl.html',
  title: 'title B',
  subtitle: 'description B'
}, {
  name: 'buzz.fizz',
  url: '/another/place',
  templateUrl: 'hello.tpl.html',
  title: 'title C',
  subtitle: 'description C'
}, {
  name: 'foo.hello.world',
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'world.tpl.html',
  title: 'title D',
  subtitle: 'description D'
}];

// Iterate over input array elements
var desiredOutput = input.reduce(function createOuput(arr, obj) {
  var names = obj.name.split('.');
  // Copy input element object as not to modify original input
  var newObj = Object.keys(obj).filter(function skipName(key) {
    return key !== 'name';
  }).reduce(function copyObject(tempObj, key) {
    if (key.match(/url$/i)) {
      tempObj[key] = obj[key];
    }
    else {
      tempObj.data[key] = obj[key];
    }

    return tempObj;
  }, {name: names[names.length - 1], data: {}});

  // Build new output array with possible recursion
  buildArray(arr, names, newObj);

  return arr;
}, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(desiredOutput, null, 4) + '</pre>');

// Helper function to search array element objects by name property
function findIndexByName(arr, name) {
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (arr[i].name === name) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}

// Recursive function that builds output array
function buildArray(arr, paths, obj) {
  var path = paths.shift();
  var index = findIndexByName(arr, path);

  if (paths.length) {
    if (index === -1) {
      arr.push({
        name: path,
        children: []
      });

      index = arr.length - 1;
    }

    if (!Array.isArray(arr[index].children)) {
      arr[index].children = [];
    }

    buildArray(arr[index].children, paths, obj);
  } else {
    arr.push(obj);
  }

  return arr;
}
```

Comment: Always nice to see a pure JS implementation as well as a comparison. I will give your solution a go along with the others posted and vote based on which best suits my requirements. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my Lodash-based attempt.

First, I discovered that `_.set` can understand deeply-nested object notation, so I use it to build a tree encoding parent-child relationships:

```
var tree = {};
input.forEach(o => _.set(tree, o.name, o));
```

This produces:

```
{
    "foo": {
        "name": "foo",
        "url": "/somewhere1",
        "templateUrl": "foo.tpl.html",
        "title": "title A",
        "subtitle": "description A",
        "bar": {
            "name": "foo.bar",
            "url": "/somewhere2",
            "templateUrl": "anotherpage.tpl.html",
            "title": "title B",
            "subtitle": "description B"
        },
        "hello": {
            "world": {
                "name": "foo.hello.world",
                "url": "/",
                "templateUrl": "world.tpl.html",
                "title": "title D",
                "subtitle": "description D"
            }
        }
    },
    "buzz": {
        "fizz": {
            "name": "buzz.fizz",
            "url": "/another/place",
            "templateUrl": "hello.tpl.html",
            "title": "title C",
            "subtitle": "description C"
        }
    }
}
```

This is actually painfully so-close-yet-so-far from the desired output. But the children's names appear as properties, alongside other properties like `title`.

Then came a laborious process of writing a recursive function that took this intermediate tree and reformatted it in the manner you wished:

1. It first needs to find the children properties, and move them to a `children` property array.
2. Then it has to deal with the fact that for long chains, intermediate nodes like `hello` in `foo.hello.world` don't have any data, so it has to insert `data: {}` and `name` properties.
3. Finally, it mops up what's left: putting the title & subtitle in a `data` property and cleaning up any `name`s that are still fully-qualified.

The code:

```
var buildChildrenRecursively = function(tree) {
  var children = _.keys(tree).filter(k => _.isObject(tree[k]));
  if (children.length > 0) {

    // Step 1 of reformatting: move children to children
    var newtree = _.omit(tree, children);
    newtree.children = children.map(k => buildChildrenRecursively(tree[k]));

    // Step 2 of reformatting: deal with long chains with missing intermediates
    children.forEach((k, i) => {
      if (_.keys(newtree.children[i]).length === 1) {
        newtree.children[i].data = {};
        newtree.children[i].name = k;
      }
    });

    // Step 3 of reformatting: move title/subtitle to data; keep last field in name
    newtree.children = newtree.children.map(function(obj) {
      if ('data' in obj) {
        return obj;
      }
      var newobj = _.omit(obj, 'title,subtitle'.split(','));
      newobj.data = _.pick(obj, 'title,subtitle'.split(','));
      newobj.name = _.last(obj.name.split('.'));
      return newobj;
    });

    return (newtree);
  }
  return tree;
};

var result = buildChildrenRecursively(tree).children;
```

The output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "url": "/somewhere1",
        "templateUrl": "foo.tpl.html",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "bar",
                "url": "/somewhere2",
                "templateUrl": "anotherpage.tpl.html",
                "data": {
                    "title": "title B",
                    "subtitle": "description B"
                }
            },
            {
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "world",
                        "url": "/",
                        "templateUrl": "world.tpl.html",
                        "data": {
                            "title": "title D",
                            "subtitle": "description D"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "data": {},
                "name": "hello"
            }
        ],
        "data": {
            "title": "title A",
            "subtitle": "description A"
        }
    },
    {
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "fizz",
                "url": "/another/place",
                "templateUrl": "hello.tpl.html",
                "data": {
                    "title": "title C",
                    "subtitle": "description C"
                }
            }
        ],
        "data": {},
        "name": "buzz"
    }
]
```

To the victor go the spoils.

Comment: Wow you did get painfully so-close-yet-so far with the _.set method. I will try out your approach along with the other solutions posted and vote which one I feel best suits my needs.

Personally i'm not a fan of lambda expressions, being relatively new to ES6 at the moment I find they make me think for that microsecond longer than necessary when reading the code. But that's just a personal preference and not a critique. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: I think `_.set` can get us even closer than I previously imagined… maybe!

Comment: Yes! With `_.set` superpowers, I submitted a second answer :P see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31064609/500207

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not use recursion, it uses a reference pointer to the previous item in the object graph.

Note this solution does utilise lodash. JSFiddle example here http://jsfiddle.net/xpb75dsn/1/

```
var input = [
    {
        name: 'foo',
        url: '/somewhere1',
        templateUrl: 'foo.tpl.html',
        title: 'title A',
        subtitle: 'description A'
    },
    {
        name: 'foo.bar',
        url: '/somewhere2',
        templateUrl: 'anotherpage.tpl.html',
        title: 'title B',
        subtitle: 'description B'
    },
    {
        name: 'buzz.fizz',
        url: '/another/place',
        templateUrl: 'hello.tpl.html',
        title: 'title C',
        subtitle: 'description C'
    },
    {
        name: 'foo.hello.world',
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'world.tpl.html',
        title: 'title D',
        subtitle: 'description D'
    }
];

var nameList = _.sortBy(_.pluck(input, 'name'));
var structure = {};

var mapNav = function(name, navItem) {
    return {
        name : name,
        url : navItem.url,
        templateUrl : navItem.templateUrl,
        data : { title : navItem.title, subtitle : navItem.subtitle },
        children : []
    };
};

_.map(nameList, function(fullPath) {
    var path = fullPath.split('.');
    var parentItem = {};
    _.forEach(path, function(subName, index) {
        var navItem = _.find(input, { name : fullPath });
        var item = mapNav(subName, navItem);
        if (index == 0) {
            structure[subName] = item;
        } else {
            parentItem.children.push(item);
        }
        parentItem = item;
    });
});


var finalStructure = Object.keys(structure).map(function(key) {
    return structure[key];
});

console.log(finalStructure);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a totally recursion-free method using lodash. It occurred to me when I was thinking about how nice `_.set` and `_.get` were, and I realized I could replace object "paths" with sequences of `children`.

First, build an object/hash table with keys equal to the `name` properties of `input` array:

```
var names = _.object(_.pluck(input, 'name'));
// { foo: undefined, foo.bar: undefined, buzz.fizz: undefined, foo.hello.world: undefined }
```

(Don't try to `JSON.stringify` this object! Since its values are all undefined, it evaluates to `{}`…)

Next, apply two transforms on each of the elements: (1) cleanup title and subtitle into a sub-property `data`, and (2) and this is a bit tricky, find all intermediate paths like `buzz` and `foo.hello` that aren't represented in `input` but whose children are. Flatten this array-of-arrays and sort them by the number of `.` in the `name` field.

```
var partial = _.flatten(
    input.map(o =>
              {
                var newobj = _.omit(o, 'title,subtitle'.split(','));
                newobj.data = _.pick(o, 'title,subtitle'.split(','));
                return newobj;
              })
        .map(o => {
          var parents = o.name.split('.').slice(0, -1);
          var missing =
              parents.map((val, idx) => parents.slice(0, idx + 1).join('.'))
                  .filter(name => !(name in names))
                  .map(name => {
                    return {
                      name,
                      data : {},
                    }
                  });

          return missing.concat(o);
        }));
partial = _.sortBy(partial, o => o.name.split('.').length);
```

This code may seem intimidating but seeing what it outputs should convince you it's pretty straightforward: it's just a flat array containing the original `input` plus all intermediate paths that aren't in `input`, sorted by the number of dots in `name`, and a new `data` field for each.

```
[
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "url": "/somewhere1",
        "templateUrl": "foo.tpl.html",
        "data": {
            "title": "title A",
            "subtitle": "description A"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "buzz",
        "data": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "foo.bar",
        "url": "/somewhere2",
        "templateUrl": "anotherpage.tpl.html",
        "data": {
            "title": "title B",
            "subtitle": "description B"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "buzz.fizz",
        "url": "/another/place",
        "templateUrl": "hello.tpl.html",
        "data": {
            "title": "title C",
            "subtitle": "description C"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "foo.hello",
        "data": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "foo.hello.world",
        "url": "/",
        "templateUrl": "world.tpl.html",
        "data": {
            "title": "title D",
            "subtitle": "description D"
        }
    }
]
```

We're almost home free. The last remaining bit of magic requires storing some global state. We're going to loop over this flat `partial` array, replacing the `name` field with a path that `_.get` and `_.set` can consume containing `children` and numerical indexes:

- `foo` gets mapped to `children.0`
- `buzz` to `children.1`,
- `foo.bar` to `children.0.children.0`, etc.

As we iteratively (not recursively!) build this sequence of paths, we use `_.set` to inject each element of `partial` above into its appropriate place.

Code:

```
var name2path = {'empty' : ''};
var out = {};
partial.forEach(obj => {
  var split = obj.name.split('.');
  var par = name2path[split.slice(0, -1).join('.') || "empty"];
  var path = par + 'children.' + (_.get(out, par + 'children') || []).length;
  name2path[obj.name] = path + '.';
  _.set(out, path, obj);
});
out = out.children;
```

This object/hash `name2path` converts names to `_.set`table paths: it's initialized with a single key, `empty`, and the iteration adds to it. It's helpful to see what this `name2path` is after this code is run:

```
{
    "empty": "",
    "foo": "children.0.",
    "buzz": "children.1.",
    "foo.bar": "children.0.children.0.",
    "buzz.fizz": "children.1.children.0.",
    "foo.hello": "children.0.children.1.",
    "foo.hello.world": "children.0.children.1.children.0."
}
```

Note how the iteration increments indexes to store more than one entry in a `children` property array.

The final resulting `out`:

```
[
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "url": "/somewhere1",
        "templateUrl": "foo.tpl.html",
        "data": {
            "title": "title A",
            "subtitle": "description A"
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "foo.bar",
                "url": "/somewhere2",
                "templateUrl": "anotherpage.tpl.html",
                "data": {
                    "title": "title B",
                    "subtitle": "description B"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "foo.hello",
                "data": {},
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "foo.hello.world",
                        "url": "/",
                        "templateUrl": "world.tpl.html",
                        "data": {
                            "title": "title D",
                            "subtitle": "description D"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "buzz",
        "data": {},
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "buzz.fizz",
                "url": "/another/place",
                "templateUrl": "hello.tpl.html",
                "data": {
                    "title": "title C",
                    "subtitle": "description C"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The embedded snippet contains just code without intermediate JSON to distract you.

Is this better than my previous submission? I think so: there's a lot less bookkeeping here, less opaque "busy code", more high-level constructs. The lack of recursion I think helps. I think the final `forEach` might be replaced with a `reduce`, but I didn't try that because the rest of the algorithm is so vector-based and iterative, I didn't want to diverge from that.

And sorry to have left everything in ES6, I love it so much :)

```js
var input = [{
  name: 'foo',
  url: '/somewhere1',
  templateUrl: 'foo.tpl.html',
  title: 'title A',
  subtitle: 'description A'
}, {
  name: 'foo.bar',
  url: '/somewhere2',
  templateUrl: 'anotherpage.tpl.html',
  title: 'title B',
  subtitle: 'description B'
}, {
  name: 'buzz.fizz',
  url: '/another/place',
  templateUrl: 'hello.tpl.html',
  title: 'title C',
  subtitle: 'description C'
}, {
  name: 'foo.hello.world',
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'world.tpl.html',
  title: 'title D',
  subtitle: 'description D'
}];

var names = _.object(_.pluck(input, 'name'));

var partial = _.flatten(
  input.map(o => {
    var newobj = _.omit(o, 'title,subtitle'.split(','));
    newobj.data = _.pick(o, 'title,subtitle'.split(','));
    return newobj;
  })
  .map(o => {
    var parents = o.name.split('.').slice(0, -1);
    var missing =
      parents.map((val, idx) => parents.slice(0, idx + 1).join('.'))
      .filter(name => !(name in names))
      .map(name => {
        return {
          name,
          data: {},
        }
      });

    return missing.concat(o);
  }));
partial = _.sortBy(partial, o => o.name.split('.').length);

var name2path = {
  'empty': ''
};
var out = {};

partial.forEach(obj => {
  var split = obj.name.split('.');
  var par = name2path[split.slice(0, -1).join('.') || "empty"];
  var path = par + 'children.' + (_.get(out, par + 'children') || []).length;
  name2path[obj.name] = path + '.';
  _.set(out, path, obj);
});
out = out.children;
```